Have there been any Christian groups in history (other than WoF) who teach calling restorations into existence by word of faith?
One feature of the Word of Faith movement's teaching is that you can "call things into existence" by faith, by which proponents primarily apply to health and wealth, since they say that because

we are given promise (Mark 11:22-24),
we are given a share in Jesus's divinity as children of God,
God wants to give us good things (Matt 7:11),
we inherit Abrahamic blessings

if we have faith that can move mountains (Matt 17:20) we can also speak restorations into existence just like how Jesus as man was given the power by God and was able to:

declare someone to be healed in the manner of Genesis 1 (see this interpretation of Matt 9:24),
command the demons to leave a possessed person (Matt 8:28-34) or
calms the storm simply by speaking (Mark 4:35-41),

noting that Jesus's disciples can do "greater things" (John 14:12) BY FAITH following the example of post-Pentecost healers like Paul & Peter, while noting that Jesus could not work many miracles in Nazareth because of unbelief (Matt 13:58).
Of course WoF movement is not Biblical, but my question is a HISTORICAL one, whether a similar movement has happened in the past 20 centuries, even if it was not as "full featured" as the 20th century charismatic-tinged Word of Faith movement.  More specifically I'm asking whether the element of calling restorations into existence by word of faith has ever been taught before, especially keeping in mind that Jesus, Paul and Peter were doing that as well.
Please note that the work of restoration itself IS orthodox because we Christians are also called into Jesus's ministry of restoration, although understood more along the lines of restoring injustice, human dignity, and most importantly peace with God through repentance, which then flows over into the restoration in our horizontal relationships, bringing healing to humanity's many facets of brokenness.  The preaching of the gospel can be seen as a means to this end.
For example, orthodox Christians can declare "your sins have been forgiven" to a repentant person, or declare "Jesus loves you" to them (thus removing shame and bringing psychological healing), which in a sense bringing something not previously there into reality.  I wonder whether there has been any group that teaches this style of explicit declaration as a standard practice by all members of the group, apart from Catholic priests declaring "I absolve you from your sins" during the Catholic Sacrament of Penance.
